# Does choosing high quality on a printer make it use more ink?

Tags: printer, ink

For example, I can choose the quality option on my printer like this. It resulted in sharper printouts but slower.

[image: Print Quality (EPSON)]

On the web some say that choosing high quality does use more ink while others say it's a myth. Which one is right?

Comment: Sooo.. were you thinking of actually selecting one of these fine answers?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your printer and how High Quality has been implemented.

On my Printers (HP) over time, High Quality does use a bit more ink and does take a bit more time to make the printed page clear and high quality text / picture features.

High Quality works for me.

A good test for you (your printer) is to print both ways and compare the results. Regular may be fine for you.

99% of the time, regular is fine for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a myth. But the printer manufacturers sure are glad this myth exists.

> To be clear, I am only talking about inkjet and no other kind of
> printer.  I am also talking about both thermal (the original) and
> piezoelectric (the new kind)  printhead designs.  This is probably true for laser printers as well but I have nothing but an assumption to back up my claim.

[After all, printer ink is one of the most expensive liquids (by volume) available to mankind, even more expensive than crude oil, medicine and even human blood"](https://neelmohile.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/use-print-to-pdf-or-draft-mode-to-save-on-printer-ink-but-not-to-print-barcodes/)

For an inkjet printer, that setting is directly proportional to amount of ink allowed into the ink chamber to be vaporized/sprayed. [This is true for both thermal and piezoelectric ink jets.](https://www.imaging.org/site/IST/Resources/Imaging_Tutorials/How_an_Ink_Jet_Printer_Works/IST/Resources/Tutorials/Inkjet_Printer.aspx)

I am not sure if it is very significant between std and high but on average draft mode [will use only around about half of the ink.](http://e-district.org/userfiles/238/file/PRINTING%20-%20Ways%20To%20Save%20Ink.pdf)

Keep in mind, ***other factors*** also infuence your ink like:

- Page coverage
- Job frequency and time without printing (has to spray itself clean)
- Paper type selection

The difference might not matter to some but to some of us "Ink N*zi"s, it makes a big difference in the life of my cartridges.

Some other links:

https://www.lexmark.com/common/images/iso-page-yields/understanding-print-cartridge-page-yields.pdf

https://www.imaging.org/site/IST/Resources/Imaging_Tutorials/How_an_Ink_Jet_Printer_Works/IST/Resources/Tutorials/Inkjet_Printer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had a friend who complained about his Epson printer using so much ink. He ended up buying a new HP printer, which "solved" his problem. Afterwards I discovered that he used the high quality printer setting. As he already used his new printer and could not return it, I didn't mention it and made sure the new printer used the normal setting. It resulted in a life-long hate for Epson printers...